# Reset Albert hotkey settings on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, configuration

I installed `Albert launcher` on my ubuntu 16.04 and it was working fine. I unchecked the `system tray Icon` option and set the hotkey to `alt + enter`.

but when I try to invoke it and pressing the `alt+enter` its not opening the Albert search box and because I unchecked the `system tray Icon` option I cant change the hotkey from UI. cause I cant open it Up.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it but it still got the same settings.

I saw somewhere that the config is in `$HOME/.config/albert/albert.conf` directory but none of the file nor the directory exists. so I cant figure it out how can I change the hotkey?

maybe from a terminal command? what should I do? is there any other way to open the settings of Albert?

Answer (score 6):

Type `albert show` in Terminal to open the setting dialog.

Comment: doesnt work for me

Answer (score 5):

Ah. I got it. [Here](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/issues/65#issuecomment-146657810)

for anyone who struggle like me I share it here:

doing this will clear the last settings and when opening the Albert it will ask for settings.

```
killall -9 albert
rm -r ~/.config/albert
rm -r ~/.config/manuelschneid3r
rm -r ~/.local/share/albert
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and the previous answers didn't work. Typing `albert preferences` in the terminal opens up the settings. To set the hotkey directly from the terminal, use `albert -k [hotkey]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually change the hotkey part of the config without deleting everything, you can edit the file `~/.config/albert/albert.conf` and edit this section:

```
[General]
hotkey=Meta+Space
```